# How to get "transcript" in youtube-api v3

Tags: youtube-api

I have started using v3 of the YouTube apis on an android device, using the java client library. Some videos that I am interested in have transcripts that I can access on the web interface (like educational videos). Is there a way to access the transcripts, if present, using the v3 apis?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about a server api or a client api?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think there is yet a documented way to get the caption track via v3 of the API. If you're authenticating with oAuth2, however, your authentication will also be good for v2 of the API, so you could do a quick call to this feed:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[VIDEOID]/captiondata/[CAPTION TRACKID]
```

to get the data you want. To retrieve a list of possible caption track IDs with v2 of the API, you access this feed:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[VIDEOID]/captions
```

That feed request also accepts some optional parameters, including language, max-results, etc. For more details, along with a sample that shows the returned format of the caption track list, see the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions#Retrieve_Caption_Set

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I obtain the [caption trackid]? I can't see that in the v3 apis either ....

Comment: This API will be dropped. How can I replace with v3?

Comment: Captions were added to V3 last week; here is the documentation. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions

Comment: `https://gdata.youtube.com` API has been moved to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/` so pls use this on as of 2018 January

Comment: Can this method retrieve transcripts of videos not owned by myself?

Answer (score 47):

I had the same problem with this... and spent like a week looking for a solution until I hit another [StackOverflow question](https://web.archive.org/web/20130723101820/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036796/how-to-extract-subtitles-from-youtube-videos).

Just do a GET request on: [http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang={LANG}&v={VIDEOID}](http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=%7BLANG%7D&v=%7BVIDEOID%7D)
You don't need any api/oauth/etc. to access this.

Comment: Do you have any examples of this working?  I tried a couple video id's along with every variation of language code I could think of and didn't get a reply.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Excelent job!

Comment: this seems to work when the captions were entered manually, as opposed to be created automagically by youtube.

Comment: just add "track=asr" to your url if you want to get the the auto-generated ones

Comment: +1 for the information but it is not working for me too, I have uploaded video and generated captions automatically `http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=h2pWeot3MJY&track=asr` but not getting caption from the video  and it does not seems possible.

Comment: None of the solutions I could find allowed me to retrieve automatically generated subtitles. Therefore I came up with a bit more complex solution. Code can be found on my GitHub if anyone is still interested: https://github.com/jdepoix/youtube-transcript-api

Comment: The list of tracks can be found with `http://video.google.com/timedtext?type=list&v={video_id}`. (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888118/5445670.)

Comment: Interesting case: I used the option @SolomonUcko mentioned (`?type=list`) to get the track list for this video: `CWlbjXwUMJI`, but then when trying to retrieve the track with `?lang=en&v=CWlbjXwUMJI` I just get a blank screen. YouTube error or is it selectively protecting some captions for some videos?

Comment: Currently, it's not working.

Comment: The post you linked to is no longer available

Answer (score 16):

With API v3 you can first grab the available transcripts with the snippet:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?videoId=U1e2VNtEqm4&part=snippet&key=(my_api_key):

```json
{
 "kind": "youtube#captionListResponse",
 "etag": "\"DsOZ7qVJA4mxdTxZeNzis6uE6ck/aGHflncRxq1Uz6m1akhrOLUWUqU\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#caption",
   "etag": "\"DsOZ7qVJA4mxdTxZeNzis6uE6ck/IC7rNKkn3SQNdovFwR6fEabUYnY\"",
   "id": "TqXDnlamg84o4bX0q2oaHz4nfWZdyiZMOrcuWsSLyPc=",
   "snippet": {
    "videoId": "U1e2VNtEqm4",
    "lastUpdated": "2016-01-25T21:50:27.142Z",
    "trackKind": "standard",
    "language": "en-GB",
    "name": "",
    "audioTrackType": "unknown",
    "isCC": false,
    "isLarge": false,
    "isEasyReader": false,
    "isDraft": false,
    "isAutoSynced": false,
    "status": "serving"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#caption",
   "etag": "\"DsOZ7qVJA4mxdTxZeNzis6uE6ck/5UP1qPkmq6mzTUaEVnFC8WqjFgU\"",
   "id": "TqXDnlamg84o4bX0q2oaHw_Y53ilUWv6vMFbk0RL3XY=",
   "snippet": {
    "videoId": "U1e2VNtEqm4",
    "lastUpdated": "2016-01-25T21:55:07.481Z",
    "trackKind": "standard",
    "language": "en-US",
    "name": "",
    "audioTrackType": "unknown",
    "isCC": false,
    "isLarge": false,
    "isEasyReader": false,
    "isDraft": false,
    "isAutoSynced": false,
    "status": "serving"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

And then pick the transcript you want:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/id?id=TqXDnlamg84o4bX0q2oaHz4nfWZdyiZMOrcuWsSLyPc=

or

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/TqXDnlamg84o4bX0q2oaHz4nfWZdyiZMOrcuWsSLyPc=

at which point you need provide an authorization key. Apparently a simple key isn't enough. Possibly because:

> Quota impact: A call to this method has a quota cost of approximately 200 units.

Note the slight difference in the URLs (`/caption/` versus `/caption?`).

All the lovely documentation is here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions

Comment: can't pick the transcript using id, showing error 404 "The caption track could not be found. Check the value of the requests <code>id</code> parameter to ensure that it is correct."

Comment: `pick the transcript you want` - this part don't work with an API Key, gives error HTTP 401, Login Required.: "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication"

Answer (score 6):

Heres some code I wrote which grabs all the caption tracks from any youtube video without having to use the API. Just plug the video URL in the `$video_url` variable.

```php
// get video id from url
$video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYX87kkyubk';
preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $video_url, $matches);

// get video info from id
$video_id = $matches[0];
$video_info = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='.$video_id);
parse_str($video_info, $video_info_array);

if (isset($video_info_array['caption_tracks'])) {
    $tracks = explode(',', $video_info_array['caption_tracks']);

    // print info for each track (including url to track content)
    foreach ($tracks as $track) {
        parse_str($track, $output);
        print_r($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have create a code based on your logic of caption trackas, if you want we can add more support together , I have added translation details  for example. https://github.com/jamesjara/php-transcript-youtube-api-and-xml-parser/blob/master/example/test.php

Comment: Seems to not work on automatically transcripted videos... :( ! So probably the way is using the Youtube API 3 with key