# API key for youtube v2, registration error

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to register a new API key to use the youtube API v2, but I get this error since 2 days ago:

"Network or server error: Could not complete the registration of the new product. Please try again later."

in https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html

Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: I want to upload captions, this is not possible with the API v3 AFAIK

Comment: [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061195/how-to-get-transcript-in-youtube-api-v3), as long as you are using oAuth2 you can use v3 for api key which also lets you use v2 just for the captions

Comment: Ok, thanks. About the v2 registration: is this a temporal issue or they're not allowing new v2 API registrations anymore?

Comment: i honestly have no idea, im assuming that they are trying to phase out v2 as it is marked as deprecated on their site so it wouldnt surprise me if they are not allowing any new registrations, youll probably want to contact support as they will know better than me