# Get latest youtube videos with transcripts

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I wish to know if there is any api that returns me a set of latest or popular videos with transcripts?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) can help you with this. You can use the [`caption:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list) to return a list of caption tracks that are associated with a specified video. Note that the API response does not contain the actual captions and that the `captions.download` method provides the ability to retrieve a caption track.

Note: You must use the optional parameter `id`, it specifies a comma-separated list of IDs that identify the caption resources that should be retrieved. Each ID must identify a caption track associated with the specified video.

For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061195/how-to-get-transcript-in-youtube-api-v3).