# Getting YouTube auto-transcript from API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to pull the auto (non-user) generated video transcripts from any of the YouTube APIs?

Comment: did you got any solution till now?

Comment: @manish1706 None of the solutions I could find allowed me to retrieve automatically generated subtitles. Therefore I implemented an API Client myself, which allows you to get automatically generated subtitles for a language of your choice. Code can be found on my GitHub if anyone is still interested: https://github.com/jdepoix/youtube-transcript-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may refer with this thread: [How to get "transcript" in youtube-api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061195/how-to-get-transcript-in-youtube-api-v3)

> If you're authenticating with oAuth2, you could do a quick call to
>   this feed:
>
> ```
> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[VIDEOID]/captiondata/[CAPTIONTRACKID]
> ```
>
> to get the data you want. To retrieve a list of possible caption track
>   IDs with v2 of the API, you access this feed:
>
> ```
> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[VIDEOID]/captions
> ```
>
> That feed request also accepts some optional parameters, including
>   language, max-results, etc. For more details, along with a sample that
>   shows the returned format of the caption track list, see the
>   documentation at
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions#Retrieve_Caption_Set

Also, here are some references which migh help:

- https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-download-the-YouTube-transcripts-that-are-generated-automatically
- http://ccm.net/faq/40644-how-to-get-the-transcript-of-a-youtube-video

Comment: gdata endpoint is unavailable: "404. That’s an error."

Answer (score 6):

As of Aug 2019 the following method you to download transcripts:

1. Open in Browser

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[Video ID]`

2. From Console type:
   `JSON.parse(ytplayer.config.args.player_response).captions.playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer.captionTracks[0].baseUrl`

Comment: Edit:Not for all videos

Comment: Which Browser and which Console?

Comment: New code that works for me is: `ytplayer.config.args.raw_player_response.captions.playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer.captionTracks[0].baseUrl`

Answer (score 4):

1 Install `youtube-transcript-api` (https://github.com/jdepoix/youtube-transcript-api), e.g.:

`pip3 install youtube_transcript_api`

2 Create `youtube_transcript_api-wrapper.py` with the following code (based partially on https://stackoverflow.com/a/65325576/2585501):

```
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

#srt = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(video_id)

videoListName = "youtubeVideoIDlist.txt"
with open(videoListName) as f:
    video_ids = f.read().splitlines()

transcript_list, unretrievable_videos = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcripts(video_ids, continue_after_error=True)

for video_id in video_ids:

    if video_id in transcript_list.keys():

        print("\nvideo_id = ", video_id)
        #print(transcript)

        srt = transcript_list.get(video_id)

        text_list = []
        for i in srt:
            text_list.append(i['text'])

        text = ' '.join(text_list)
        print(text)
```

3 Create `youtubeVideoIDlist.txt` containing a list of video_ids

4 `python3 youtube_transcript_api-wrapper.py`