# How to get Youtube video transcript with YT API

Tags: youtube-api

I relate to this solution, which doesn't work for me as expected: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35555773/1992004

Example URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WECQWfbrDRA

Accessing YT API with request, recommended in the cited solution, https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?videoId=WECQWfbrDRA&part=snippet&key=MYKEY I get an answer without transcript:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#captionListResponse",
  "etag": "_Q7mhkZOxmnB-OUYZtFh3NfoQTA",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#caption",
      "etag": "inJmvEc9uoy20P6cTHGDrBw7Ucw",
      "id": "AUieDaY04UW8eDU0F_kn4QlGzc7lJriXOz42Nqc20cmkmQN759U",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "WECQWfbrDRA",
        "lastUpdated": "2023-12-12T18:47:57.150575Z",
        "trackKind": "asr",
        "language": "de",
        "name": "",
        "audioTrackType": "unknown",
        "isCC": false,
        "isLarge": false,
        "isEasyReader": false,
        "isDraft": false,
        "isAutoSynced": false,
        "status": "serving"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But accessing example video with a service like [this](https://youtubetranscript.com/?v=WECQWfbrDRA), transcript exists.

Am I doing something wrong?

PS: It seems to me, 'caption' in terms of YT API is something other as transcript of the video.

Comment: [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Captions: download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) endpoint is only usable by the channel owning the given videos we want the captions of (source: [this StackOverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653865/downloading-captions-always-returns-a-403#comment49414961_30660549), I verified this fact). As a result you can use [my low-level approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70013529) or use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp)